# Vector resize function not working properly c++

Tags: c++, vector, vector-class-library

I have been making a custom vector class, however I have been bumping into a problem. The problem being that my vector just won't resize, the size stays 0.
Anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

```
void resize(const int newSize) {
            // If size is zero, give error
            if (newSize < 0) {
                throw std::out_of_range("Vector");
            }
            // If the given size is smaller than the size that it is now, just ignore
            else if (newSize < capacity) {
                return;
            } 
            // Else, make a new array and copy everything over
            T* newArr = new T[newSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
                newArr[i] = data[i];
            }
            delete[] data;
            capacity = newSize;
            data = newArr;
        }
```

EDIT 1:
Here is the push_back function where resize is needed:

```
template <typename T> void pushBack(Vector<T>& vector, T& value){
    unsigned int oldSize = vector.size();
    vector.resize(oldSize+1);
    vector.at(oldSize) = value;
}
```

EDIT 2:
Here are the vector deffinitions:

```
        Vector(const int newSize) {
            if (newSize < 0) {
                throw std::out_of_range("Vector");
            }
            data = new T[newSize];
            capacity = newSize;
            actualSize = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Do you differentiate capacity and size?

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Sidenote: If you don't want the size to become negative you could also use an unsigned integer type instead throwing exceptions.

Comment: @Jarod42 What do you mean by that? :D

Comment: @churill If I understood it right, this should suffice! :D

Comment: Minimal reproducible exemple should allow us to copy paste your code and compile it. As-is, there are missing stuff, a minimal class `Vector` (members + constructors (copy/move might be deleted)).

Comment: What is the initial value of `capacity`?

Comment: `std::vector` differentiate `size` (current number of elements), and `capacity` (max number of element without reallocations). Showing Vector definition would answer that question.

Comment: Done! Thanks for learning me how to post good formatted questions on here!

Comment: Can you answer the following question: can everyone else in the world take what you've shown in the question, cut/paste ***exactly as shown*** into an empty file, compile, then run and reproduce your problem? Of course, at this time the answer would be "no". So, this is still not a [mre]. And until you do show a [mre], it is unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you what the problem is, but only make random guesses.

Comment: Looks like your `resize()` function never changes the value of `actualSize`.

Comment: BTW, you should be consistent between `size` and `capacity`. `capacity = newSize;` look strange.